# How can I get the coordinates of any given address using CoreLocation framework and not google Maps API?

Tags: iphone, gps, coordinates, google-maps, core-location

I'm interested in finding out the coordinates of "any" given address and not just the current location using only CoreLocation.Framework. I do not wish to use google maps API or yahoo maps or any other third Party maps API.
Is it possible? How can I get the coordinates of any address?

Thanks

Comment: how about reverse geocoding? Can we get the address of a place from its coordinates using only CoreLocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT - Thanks to a comment, I realized my original answer is dreadfully out of date. At the time, in late 2009, it was a massive pain to geocode - reverse geocoding was possible via Core Location APIs, but forward geocoding was not possible until iOS 5.

But in iOS 6.1 MapKit introduced an even better API, the MKLocalSearch class. It's very easy to perform search queries for an address and then inspect the properties of the returned objects.

Comment: @Dex are you saying that Geocoding is available in IOS 5? What API can we use for that?

Comment: @fishinear Yes. Map Kit provides the MKLocalSearch API. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/EnablingSearch/EnablingSearch.html